# В чем смысл public полей, если они нарушают принцип инкапсуляции?

Tags: ооп, инкапсуляция, дизайн-языка

В ООП есть три основных принципа:

- Наследование,
- Инкапсуляция
- Полиморфизм.

Если кратко - смысл инкапсуляции скрытие полей. Для чего разработчики языков программирования дают возможность создавать public поля, если они нарушают принцип инкапсуляции?

Comment: А потом вы увидите голанг который ооп но в нем нет полиморфизма, и наследования :) а потом встретите функциональные языки в которых вообще от парадигмы ООП в том виде как ее пиарят - ничего не осталось :) ООП - представление некой сущности как ```объекта``` и никакого отношения к перечисленным вам механикам не имеет.

Comment: насколько помню, принцип инкапсуляции не в скрытии полей, а в единении данных и методов их обработки в единый компонент. паблик поля не противоречат этому принципу :)

Comment: а наличие тривиальных геттеров и сеттеров чем-то отличается от публичного поля? Но первое - плохо, инкапсуляция нарушается, а второе - все так делают)

Answer (score 6):

Вот что говорит майкрософт по этому поводу:

> Инкапсуляция - Скрытие внутреннего состояния и функций объекта и предоставление доступа только через открытый набор функций

Публичные **свойства** позволяющие получить и/или установить значение приватного поля **инкапсулируют** эту самую логику получить и/или установить.

UPD: Свойства и поля - это абсолютно разные вещи (судя по вашему профилю вы занимаетесь C#), так вот в С# - свойства это синтаксический сахар над двумя методами: GetField, SetField. В большинства языках программирования свойства выглядят следующим образом:

```
private SmthType field;
public SmthType GetField()
{
   return field;
}
public void SetField(SmthType value)
{
   field = value;
}
```

В C# же:

```
public SmthType MyProperty { get; set; }
```

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private SmthType <Property>k__BackingField;

public SmthType MyProperty
{
   [CompilerGenerated]
   get
   {
      return <Property>k__BackingField;
   }
   [CompilerGenerated]
   set
   {
      <Property>k__BackingField = value;
   }
}
```

После чего этот код на C# преобразуется в IL код, а в этом IL коде `get` и `set` - это методы

Как мы можем видеть, это два **метода**, в которых вы можете инкапсулировать какую-то логику. Модификаторы доступа представляют способ инкапсуляции членов.

Публичные члены класса как могут, так и не могут нарушать инкапсуляцию, всё зависит от контекста вашего класса, если у вас есть много "вспомогательных" методов, то их стоит сделать private - тобишь инкапсулировать внутрь объекта класса.

---

Инкапсуляция, как и другие парадигмы ООП, различные способы проектирования - это способ облегчить жизнь самому себе и другим программистам в вашей команде. Если Ваш код будет содержать только публичные члены - то его будет гораздо сложнее понять и использовать, вплоть до невозможности. Все модные технологии и прочее - это способ облегчить жизнь программисту, поскольку конечному потребителю вообще наплевать кто у вас там public, а кто private.

Comment: Внутреннее состояние - это значения полей/свойств. Публичные поля/свойства нарушают основной принцип - Инкапсуляции. А инкапсуляция это основной принцип ООП. Так вот зачем нам публичные поля/свойства? Мы полностью можем обойтись без публичных полей/свойств и использовать геттеры и сеттеры, при этом в сеттерах проводить проверки при записи данных.

Comment: Геттеры и сеттеры - это просто методы. Свойство - это два метода (get_X и set_X). Публичные поля нарушают инкапсуляцию, а свойства - нет (поле и свойство это разные вещи), поскольку содержат логику взаимодействия с этими самыми полями (как получить/как задать). Да, некоторые публичные свойства могут действительно нарушать инкапсуляцию, но в основном нарушением инкапсуляции является создание публичных полей/методов/свойств которые используют внутреннюю логику и нужны только для внутренней логики класса

Comment: @xmokko я обновил ответ немного

Answer (score 1):

Заглянем в [Википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8):

> В общем случае в разных языках программирования термин **«инкапсуляция»**
> относится к **одной или обеим одновременно** следующим нотациям:
>
> - механизм языка, позволяющий **ограничить доступ** одних компонентов программы к другим;
> - языковая конструкция, позволяющая **связать данные с методами**, предназначенными для обработки этих данных.

В разных языках программирования с ограничением доступа дела обстоят довольно по-разному (в каких-то языках его практически нет, при том, что ООП там есть), да и те механизмы ограничения доступа, которые даже если есть в языке, используются не всегда в полной мере, поэтому однозначно относить термин **инкапсуляция** только к **ограничению доступа** не стоит.

Лично я предпочитаю второй вариант трактовки этого термина - то есть механизм, позволяющий держать вместе данные и методы, относящиеся к одной сущности (обычно это называется **класс** в объектно-ориентированных языках программирования).

Answer (score 1):

Ничего они не нарушают. Наоборот. Если из объекта ничего не торчит наружу, то и сделать с ним ничего нельзя. И скрывать в таком объекте нечего. Поэтому public-члены в любом осмысленном ООП языке обязательны. Как и protected-члены в любом ООП языке, даже бессмысленном: что-то скрывать надо.

Answer (score 0):

Смысл в том, что популярным может быть только мультипарадигменный язык. То есть язык, который позволяет смешивать и частично нарушать все парадигмы, которые он поддерживает.

Если вы загоните программиста в слишком жесткие рамки, то язык популярным не будет, вот и всё.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/800528)

Comment: @DmitryK, поясните, пожалуйста

Comment: В вопросе ничего нет про популярность языка. Смысл Вашего ответа абсолютно верный, только к вопросу относится очень относительно. Правильнее было бы оформить его в качестве комментария.