# Как работает инкапсуляция в dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, консоль

```
namespace TestOne
{
    class Program
    {
        public string test = "test";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            test = "tt"; // Здесь ошибка поле не видно. как, почему?
        }
    }
}
```

Текст ошибки:

Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Program.test" требуется ссылка на объект. [TestOne]

Comment: Внимание на метод, какой он? `static`, а что можно вызвать в `static`? Правильно, либо другой статичный объект, либо проинициализированный объект, то есть, варианта 2: 1. `public static string test ...`. 2. `new Program().test = "tt";`. Если вы учитесь, советую сделать отдельный класс и на нем эксперементировать, а не в дефолтном классе консоли.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Оформи как ответ, пожалуйста) Да, я понял в чем дело, спасибо

Comment: Почитайте вот это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1424744/422180

Comment: @voidsMark Пожалуй откажусь. Можете сделать это самостоятельно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Хорошо, оформлю :3 Просто хотел сказать спасибо так, как принято на ресурсе-проголосовать за ответ. Так или иначе спасибо, очень помог и дал понимание что стоит подучить

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `Main` консольного приложения имеет модификатор `static`, который запрещает обращаться к не статичным членам класса. Для того, чтобы ими воспользоваться, необходимо либо сделать член класса статичным (добавив модификатор `static`), либо создать экземпляр класса.

```
public static string test = "test";
```

или

```
new Program().test = "tt";
```

За помощь в решении проблемы спасибо @EvgeniyZ