# Какая разница между readonly, const и свойства без set. Почему const выводится также как и static? (C#)

Tags: c#

Я пишу код на C# и не понимаю разницу между `readonly`, `const` и свойства без `set`. А также не понимаю, почему const выводится так же как и `static`:

```
using System;
class HelloWorld {
    readonly public static int num1 = 
     10;
    public static int num2{get;} = 15;
    public const num3 = 20;
  
    static void Main() {
    }
}
```

Comment: `readonly` поле можно при желании инициализировать в конструкторе класса, а `const` нужно задать сразу при описании поля. Про свойство без `set` так сходу не скажу, но основное что это всё-таки свойство, у него можно задать какое-то поведение в геттере, а так особо вроде разницы не будет.

Comment: Значение `const` фиксируется на этапе компиляции и уже никогда из кода не может быть изменено. Значение `readonly` фиксируется уже в рантайме после завершения исполнения конструктора класса. Из конструктора может меняться и многократно.

Comment: Собственно поэтому `const` по сути являются константами класса, нет смысла их плодить в каждом экземпляре, когда их значение всегда одинаково для всех.

Answer (score 3):

Разница состоит в том, что константы имеют значения еще на этапе компиляции, так же они являются статичными, точно такие же как и вы руками делаете `static`, буквально ничем не отличается. `Readonly` полям можно установить значение лишь единожды - в конструкторе.

Если посмотрим на IL кода ниже:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public const string MyConst = "myConst";
   private readonly string _myReadonly;
   
   public MyClass(string myReadonly)
   {
     _myReadonly = myReadonly;
   }
}
```

То получим как раз таки то, о чём я и говорю выше. Значение у константы известно + статично, а поля `readonly` просто объявлены как "только для инициализации в конструкторе":

```
.field public static literal string MyConst = "1234"
.field private initonly string _myReadonly
```

Ну а `get-only` свойства компилируются только лишь в 1 метод `get_BackingField`, в то время как `get-set` свойства компилируются в 2 метода: `get_BackingField` и `set_BackingField`.

Про то, во что компилируются свойства можно почитать [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1424744/422180), хоть в ссылке вопрос о другом, но я там наглядно показываю что такое свойство в C#.

И, если не ошибаюсь, то константы определяются в заголовках PE файлов (exe или dll)